# How to set up Jmeter ramp up time?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Please I want to know How to set up Jmeter ramp up time ? 
and if having error in some requests due to the ramp up time >> ignore the test or how can I handle this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ramp-up period is the time required for all threads representing virtual users to start.
I.e:
  This is configuration of test plan:

```
Number of Threads (users): 100
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 10
Loop Count : No
```

<== It means that every 0.1 second (=ram-up period/number of threads) a new thread starts giving 100 running threads after 10 seconds. 
       So, in your case, you can adjust according whatever you want.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve you can also use the following test elements:

[Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) - to hold the threads until specified number will be reached and release them at the same moment.

[Constant Throughput Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to specify exact load in requests-per-second.

For second question:

> if having error in some requests due to the ramp up time >> ignore the
>   test or how can I handle this problem

<== You can set it on your "Thread group", there're 5 actions for your selections:
    - Continue
    - Start Next Thread Loop
    - Stop thread
    - Stop test
    - Stop test now

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for your interest to reply on me,
The first point is ok defined 
and the second point, I mean that when running plan after select continue and set up number of threads and ramp up time i found that some requests have the rate of error, what can i do ??

Comment: --> ignore the result of this request and change the ramp up time or I consider this results if the error rate is small , Thanks for your help