# Jmeter rampup capabilities

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I know rampup has been explained here [How to set up Jmeter ramp up time?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/13352/19076) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/17288545/4675568.

But something bothers me. On my local machine, I'm trying to do 10000 threads in a 3 seconds rampup time.
Does the rampup too short ? Do I need to use a more powerful machine for the load testing ? Do I need to decrease the thread number ?
Because in my case, the 10000th thread starts 2min after the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ask for answers, get them yourself.

1. Make sure your JMeter configuration is **optimal** in terms of Java Heap space, Garbage Collector options, test is well-behaved and being run in non-GUI mode. See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for JMeter performance tweaks listed and explained.
2. Configure [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to kick off 10k virtual users and start executing your test, but do this **gradually**. This will allow to check where the problems start occurring.
3. While doing step 2 make sure you monitor the main health metrics of the host where JMeter is running, to wit: CPU, RAM, Swap usage, Network and Disk IO. When one of the metrics starts exceeding i.e 95% - most likely this is your bottleneck. This could be done using your operating system built-in tools or [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).

Be aware that JMeter supports [Distributed Testing Mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when your test is being executed in parallel by several JMeter instances on different hosts, for instance if you have 2 machines you can use as load generators - you will need to kick off 5k threads on each JMeter remote engine.

Comment: Nice recommendations, thanks, I'll give a try !